# Django model field for PostgreSQL NUMERIC data type

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, numeric

I'm using Django to create an application (using PostgreSQL) that needs a column numeric(15,6), but I'm not finding a method to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with a decimal field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From PostgreSQL docs:

> **The types decimal and numeric are equivalent**. Both types are part of the SQL standard.

So you can use Django's `DecimalField`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6)
```

Some docs:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield

Comment: Can DecimalField be used without specyfing precision and scale so values will be taken with precision and scale as they are in database?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping to add onto to the answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment. This is about how to add a Django model field for PostgreSQL NUMERIC type without specifying precision and scale.

As said in the above answer, we have `NUMERIC(precision, scale)` in postgres. In `models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=6)`, `max_digits` maps to `precision` and `decimal_places` maps to `scale`.

In the postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL), it says that 'NUMERIC without any precision or scale creates an “unconstrained numeric” column in which numeric values of any length can be stored, up to the implementation limits. A column of this kind will not coerce input values to any particular scale, whereas numeric columns with a declared scale will coerce input values to that scale.'

This means if you have `NUMERIC(15,6)`, if you input `1.2`, the data inserted in to postgres will be coerced to `1.200000`. But if you have `NUMERIC`, then the data inserted will be as it is, i.e. `1.2`.

I found [this great article](https://steve.dignam.xyz/2019/10/24/arbitrary-precision-decimal-fields/) talking about how you can create a new `ArbitraryDecimalField` in `models.py` that overrides the requirement of declaring `max_digits` and `decimal_places` in Django `models.DecimalField` so that we can specify postgres `NUMERIC` data type without declaring precision and scale. This works when I test with `Model.objects.create()` to create and save the object directly in the database.

If I want to create the object through a POST request using an API written in Django REST framework, I get errors related to the `rest_framework.serializers`:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'max_digits' and 'decimal_places'
```

Diggging into the django rest framework source code [serializers.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py) and [fields.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py), to prevent the error in the Django project serializers.py, we need to set `max_digits` and `decimal_places` in the `serializers.DecimalField` as None. Here is a sample.

models.py (based on [this great article](https://steve.dignam.xyz/2019/10/24/arbitrary-precision-decimal-fields/))

```
from django.db import models

class ArbitraryDecimalField(models.DecimalField):
    def _check_decimal_places(self):
        return []
    def _check_max_digits(self):
        return []

    def _check_decimal_places_and_max_digits(self):
        return []

    def db_type(self, connection):
        # pg or bust
        assert connection.settings_dict["ENGINE"] == "django.db.backends.postgresql"
        return "numeric"

class SampleModel(models.Model):
    my_num = ArbitraryDecimalField()
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import SampleModel

class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    my_num = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=None, decimal_places=None)
    class Meta:
        model = SampleModel
        fields = ['my_num']
```